# compile error on Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

How can i fix it

```
Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iRadio.app/iRadio normal i386
cd /Users/ragopor/Desktop/iRadio
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.5
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.2.sdk -L/Users/ragopor/Desktop/iRadio/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/ragopor/Desktop/iRadio/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/ragopor/Desktop/iRadio -filelist /Users/ragopor/Desktop/iRadio/build/iRadio.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iRadio.build/Objects-normal/i386/iRadio.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -framework MediaPlayer -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/ragopor/Desktop/iRadio/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iRadio.app/iRadio

ld: warning: in /Users/ragopor/Desktop/iRadio/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer, missing required architecture i386 in file
Undefined symbols:
  ".objc_class_name_MPMoviePlayerController", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@MPMoviePlayerController in iRadioAppDelegate.o
  "_MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification", referenced from:
      _MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification$non_lazy_ptr in iRadioAppDelegate.o
  "_MPMoviePlayerScalingModeDidChangeNotification", referenced from:
      _MPMoviePlayerScalingModeDidChangeNotification$non_lazy_ptr in iRadioAppDelegate.o
  "_MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification", referenced from:
      _MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification$non_lazy_ptr in iRadioAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you need to include the MediaFramework in your project.

Comment: Why is it loading the MediaPlayer framework from /Users/ragopor/Desktop/iRadio?  That's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while all frameworks and compiling sources were added. What fixed my issue was to delete `~/ProjectFolder/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer.exec` file, and then build and run, and it worked!